# How to dismiss two modal view controllers at once?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller A which in on the navigation stack.
A modally presents another controller B which in turn can modally presents another controller C.

When the user hits a button in C I want to dismiss both C and B to return to A.
How can I dismiss both B and C at once?

The code below works, but is it safe to do this?

```
    let p = self.presentingViewController
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        p?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: If you are using storyboard, you might want to use `unwind segue`. Take a look here for example https://cocoacasts.com/how-do-unwind-segues-work/ .

Comment: @kiwisip Good suggestion but sorry I didn't mention that B and C can also be presented from several other controllers apart from A, so I'd need several unwind segues and C would need to know from where B was originally presented, so that could get a bit messy. So I'm looking for something that C can do on its own (or C and B if B has to be also involved in the dismissal).

Comment: You can dismiss the presentingViewController directily, it should dismiss all the presentedViewControllers

Comment: @Luca Iaco, thats what I thought and tried, but it didn't work when doing self.presentingViewController.dismiss(...) from within C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the topmost view controller a property. Make sure that `B` sets the topmost view controller for `C`.

```
class C: UIViewController {

    var topmostViewController: UIViewController?

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        // If topmostViewController was not set, then assume
        // the presenting view controller is to be dismissed.
        (topmostViewController ?? presentingViewController)?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

This gives you a good deal of flexibility as to which view controller does the dismissing.